# Ubuntu 12.04 : Adding widgets to the login panel

Tags: 12.04, lightdm

not sure where to start here, it's an area of config I'm not familiar with.

Just wondering, is it possible to write some custom widgets for the panel that appears on the login screen? I've found plenty on how to change the wallpaper etc, but no one seems to talk about the panel itself.

cheers

Comment: it appears I am using the unity-greeter - still no idea on how to create a new widget for the menubar though!